# Scala: Dealing with optional XML elements and Case Classes

Tags: xml, scala, coding-style, xml-parsing, implicit-conversion

I'm looking for a better way of building objects from XML in Scala, similar to what's [happening in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739811/processing-optional-xml-attributes-in-scala).  I'd like to read xml which may contain missing elements.  Currently, I'm using a case class:

```
case class Content(name:String, description:String, someDouble: Double)
```

When reading xml, I'm passing in a Node to the following function:

```
def buildContent(node: Node) = {
    Content((node \ "name").text, 
            (node \ "description").text,
            (node \ "someDouble")
}
```

My problem is that "someDouble" may or may not be present in the current XML snippet, which would be fine if this was a string but I need to treat it as a double.  Currently I'm handling this with an implicit conversion

```
implicit def NodeSeqToDouble(value: NodeSeq) = {
   value.text match {
     case "" => 0.0
     case s:String => s.toDouble
   }
}
```

Which works, but seems verbose and somewhat ugly.  I'm wondering if there is a "best practices" way of dealing with optional elements when a type conversion is involved on an optional xml element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your code is that after the conversion it si impossible to tell whether the `double` value was missing or it was present but set to `0.0`.

The fist thing that comes to mind are scalas `Option`.
Your case class would look like:

```
case class Content(name:String, description:String, someDouble: Option[Double])
```

And the conversion would be:

```
implicit def NodeSeqToDouble(value: NodeSeq) = {
  value.text match {
    case "" => None
    case s:String => Some(s.toDouble)
  }
}
```

This would mean that after the conversion the information whether the `double` was present or missing is still retained.

Comment: Interesting, I like that approach.  You could then leverage pattern matching if you need to process that value.  One follow up question:  is a case class the best option for a DTO, and if so, is there a different way to specify optional (nullable) values, or is Option[Type] the best fit?

Comment: @mhamrah Case classes seem a reasonable approach for DTO's.  As for optional (nullable) values AFAIK `Option[Type]` is scalas standard approach to them. (See: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option)